# Display which Wordpress template and template_part files are used to construct a page?

Tags: wordpress, templates

Trying to work with JetPack's Portfolio Custom Content Type and the Underscores portfolio component, but not entirely sure if the right templates are loading.

Is there a configuration or plugin that will display in the browserwhich Wordpress template and template_part files are used to construct a page?

Answer (score 0):

Try

`<?php echo '<!-- ' . basename( get_page_template() ) . ' -->'; ?>`

in your `footer.php`.

That uses `get_page_template` to dump the name of the template inside comment ticks - `<!--` and `-->` - so it is visible in source but invisible to front end viewers.

Or use

```
<?php get_current_template( true ); ?>
```

if you want it fully visible on the front end.

See https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/

There is a plugin that offers that function: https://wordpress.org/plugins/reveal-template/ And this one that offers that and lots of other debugging info: https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/